# Magento 1: Different collections from external script and from helper

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, custom, product-collection

I have a custom product resource collection, which I need to export to CSV. The collection is made up like this:

```
/** @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addPriceData();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
$collection->addAttributeToSelect(array("product_id","sku","created_at","price","special_price","name","qty","row","shelf","level","single_copy","additional_information","condition","last_ordered"));
$collection->addExpressionAttributeToSelect(
    'last_ordered',
    '(SELECT created_at FROM sales_flat_order_item WHERE sales_flat_order_item.sku = e.sku ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1)',
    'last_ordered'
);
$collection->joinTable(
    array(
        'qbtp' => 'qb_tools_inventory_product'
    ),
    'product_id = entity_id',
    array(
        'qty' => 'qty',
        'row' => 'row',
        'shelf' => 'shelf',
        'level' => 'level',
    )
);
$collection->getSelect()->group('qbtp.product_id');
$collection->getSelect()->order(array('last_ordered'));
```

As a proof of concept I made up a quick solution in an external PHP file and initialized the Magento framework in it like this:

```
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();
```

Now the POC works and I am building a separate module for the feature.

**The strange thing: If I paste the same collection code into a helper or into a controller, I get an empty collection!** The SQL query I get is also different:

From external script (works):

```
SELECT `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `e`.`status`, `e`.`sku`, `e`.`created_at`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`condition`, `e`.`condition_value`, IF(at_last_ordered.value_id > 0, at_last_ordered.value, at_last_ordered_default.value) AS `last_ordered`, (SELECT created_at FROM sales_flat_order_item WHERE sales_flat_order_item.sku = e.sku ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1) AS `last_ordered`, `qbtp`.`qty`, `qbtp`.`row`, `qbtp`.`shelf`, `qbtp`.`level` FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_last_ordered_default` ON (`at_last_ordered_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_last_ordered_default`.`attribute_id` = '194') AND `at_last_ordered_default`.`store_id` = 0 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_last_ordered` ON (`at_last_ordered`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_last_ordered`.`attribute_id` = '194') AND (`at_last_ordered`.`store_id` = 1) INNER JOIN `qb_tools_inventory_product` AS `qbtp` ON (qbtp.product_id =e.entity_id) WHERE (e.status = 1) AND (e.status = '1') GROUP BY `qbtp`.`product_id` ORDER BY `last_ordered` ASC
```

From the helper or controller of the separate extension:

```
SELECT `e`.*, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `at_status`.`value` AS `status`, `at_last_ordered`.`value` AS `last_ordered`, (SELECT created_at FROM sales_flat_order_item WHERE sales_flat_order_item.sku = e.sku ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1) AS `last_ordered`, `qbtp`.`qty`, `qbtp`.`row`, `qbtp`.`shelf`, `qbtp`.`level` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '0' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status` ON (`at_status`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status`.`attribute_id` = '96') AND (`at_status`.`store_id` = 0) LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_last_ordered` ON (`at_last_ordered`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_last_ordered`.`attribute_id` = '194') AND (`at_last_ordered`.`store_id` = 0) INNER JOIN `qb_tools_inventory_product` AS `qbtp` ON (qbtp.product_id =e.entity_id) WHERE (at_status.value = '1') GROUP BY `qbtp`.`product_id` ORDER BY `last_ordered` ASC
```

Why is that???

Thanks a lot for any input!